Jakarta Server Faces 4.0 causing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
     
            <!-- JSF: Mojarra, PrimeFaces -->
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>${primefaces-version}</version>
                <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>${primefaces-version}</version>
                <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            </dependency>
    
    </dependencyManagement>

    com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
                                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
                                 at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:410)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:338)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:183)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:263)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:286)
                                 at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
                                 at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:280)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:195)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:265)
                                 at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
                                 at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:263)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:179)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4436)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4876)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:643)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1939)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:536)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1661)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                                 ... 64 more
    15-May-2024 04:25:41.331 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    15-May-2024 04:25:41.332 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/bobWeb] startup failed due to previous errors
    15-May-2024 04:25:46.184 SEVERE [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
                  jakarta.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:434)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:323)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:183)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:263)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:108)
                                 at com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl.<init>(ELContextImpl.java:60)
                                 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:300)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4482)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:242)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:175)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:643)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1939)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:536)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1661)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                                 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
                  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
                                 at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:639)
                                 at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:431)
                                 ... 48 more
                  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.<init>()
                                 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:626)
                                 ... 49 more
    15-May-2024 04:25:51.753 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\sosomanna\.SmartTomcat\BobGuiWeb\bobWeb\conf\Catalina\localhost\bobWeb.xml] has finished in [391,812] ms
    15-May-2024 04:25:51.760 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    15-May-2024 04:25:59.803 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to start component [Connector["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8012"]]
                  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
                                 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1046)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:450)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                                 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The AJP Connector is configured with secretRequired="true" but the secret attribute is either null or "". This combination is not valid.
                                 at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProtocol.start(AbstractAjpProtocol.java:277)
                                 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1043)
                                 ... 12 more
    
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
                             at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                             at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
                          

    java:171)
                             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                             at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
                             at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
                             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                             at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
                             at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory


Make sure you are using a JakartaEE version of Primefaces. Looks like you are using an older version which is JavaEE and not JakartaEE compatible.

Tomcat does NOT provide org.glassfish:jakarta.faces. Remove the provided from there. See the first duplicate.

Whilst not the cause of the observable problem, you need to clearly understand that Tomcat does actually also NOT provide jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api and that you can't install it in Tomcat by removing the  and that you therefore need to be extremely careful with that while writing your code. See the second duplicate.

@M.Deinum: the PrimeFaces dependencies already correctly have the jakarta set.
